# Gmail strips cursor:pointer style

Tags: html, css, gmail

I am trying to do something like

```
label::after{
    cursor: pointer;
    ...
}
```

and

```
<label>
    <input type = "checkbox">
</label>
```

(note the checkbox is hidden with CSS and `::after` styles are applied to make a nice button)

When this is run in Chrome, everything works. In Gmail (desktop), however, it does not. A normal cursor is displayed. **Why?**